# Symfony form theme flat items

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have a very nested object with collectiontypes and subforms they are only needed for the database mapping. In the frontend I want just output all fields on the same html tree. But currently he will also add my `div` around subforms and collection types. Here my theme

```
{% block form_row %}
<div class="form-item"  {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{%- block form_widget_compound -%}
    {%- if form.parent is empty -%}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {{- block('form_rows') -}}
    {{- form_rest(form) -}}
{%- endblock form_widget_compound -%}
```

Example Object:

- username
- email
- contact (one-to-one)

  - firstname
  - lastname
  - contactaddresses (one-to-many)

    - address ( many-to-many )
    - street
    - number
    - zip

As I have multiple object like this in my project and I want to use the same form theme for all. How I can detect if its a `subform` or `collectionType` to not render my added div in the `form_row`.

First i thought the compound parameter is what I looked for but `compound` is also true when the form type is a choice.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution was to set the `getBlockPrefix` for every form type with the same entity to the same. Not the solution I'm happy with it but currently seems to be the only solution.